# jquery position animation issue in chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, html

so I have a div with the following css:

```
#MyDiv {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    top: 0px;
    right: 50%;
    width: 49%;
    height: 99%;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

and i'm animating it to the right with jquery by 800 pixels. In firefox the final position is the desired one, however in chrome and opera it's wrong.

```
    alert($("#MyDiv").position().left);
    $("#MyDiv").animate({left: "+=" + 800 + "px"}, 1000, "linear", function() {
        alert($("#MyDiv").position().left);
    });
```

in firefox the initial left position is 23 (first alert) and the final 823 (second alert)
in chrome and opera the final position is 800

am i doing something wrong? there is a requirement to keep the css unchanged.

p.s. ie8 has also some issues but to a lesser extent than chrome and opera

thanks in advance.

**edit** jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Q8K2R/

Comment: use console.log() for such things

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5A2Nm/ works as expected in chrome, can you make this demo to repeat the problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8K2R/ initial pos 3 final 800, should be 803

Comment: yeap, it should be 804.3xxx

Comment: @eicto even your demo in chrome goes from -2 to 800. chrome 24

Comment: yes, i understand problem now, btw, if you use 802 it return 802.4000244140625 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way is to setup css `left` attribute, because animation works with css, and here is no guarantie, that left attribute contains correct calculated data, so fix can be like

```
var mydiv=$("#MyDiv");
mydiv.css({left: mydiv.position().left});
```

before animate
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5A2Nm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just calculate the position before animating the style:

```
`var _left = $("#MyDiv").position().left + 800 + 'px';
$("#MyDiv").animate({left: _left}, 1000, "linear", function() {
    alert($("#MyDiv").position().left);
}); `
```

Comment: may be that is only solution, btw, in jQuery, you not need 'px' when do animate